# Facebook static HTML iFrame - Use JQuery to interact with the parent CSS?

Tags: jquery, facebook, iframe, parent, static-html

I have come accross the static HTML app for facebook pages that allows us to build a landing page made up of HTML, CSS and even Javascript. eg. http://www.facebook.com/divethegap?sk=app_190322544333196

Now is it possible to interact with the parent window. I'd like to change the overall background to something else if possible, preferably an image from our website.

As a test I tried `$('body', window.parent.document).css('background-color', '#888');`

Nothing hapenned. I can imagine many reason why facebook would limit or restrict entirely the ability to ammend the parent window, but in the case of CSS for the parent I wondered if it were possible. It would certainly brighten up the overall theme considerably.

Comment: Facebook doesn't want apps drawing on their sandbox and is putting up a big fence in order to not let them.  That's why they hide apps away inside of an iFrame hosted on a different domain.    :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is because of cross domain access restrictions you cannot access any thing from the parent window if it is not in the same domain.